# Basis of Kernel of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Determine a basis of $ker(T)$ and $T(R^5)$ for a linear map $T : R^5 → R^3$ whose matrix (relative to the standard basis) equals

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 9\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 2\\
0 &2 & -2 & -6 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

To find the basis for kernel, I just let the matrix time a vector [v1,...,v5] s.t. it equals 0 and solve for the basis. For $T(R^5)$ basis, do I just reduce the matrix to rref and find the basis of the rref?

In addition, what does it mean "(relative to the standard basis)" in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to the standard basis just means we don't have to use a change of basis matrix to compute the kernel.  So we get $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 9\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 2\\
0 &2 & -2 & -6 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 9\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 2\\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.  Now "back-substitute".  Get $b-c-3d+2e=0,a+5d+9e=0$.  So $\{(-9,-2,0,0,1),(-5,3,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0,0)\}$ is a basis for the kernel.

Comment: thank you, so what if we have a change of basis matrix, what does that mean?

Comment: Well if the matrix is given to you in some nonstandard basis you can use the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors (and or its inverse) to change to the standard basis.  Then follow the same procedure.

Comment: Or you could leave everything in terms of the nonstandard basis.

Answer (score 0):

You find the kernel if you evaluate the augmented matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 9 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 2&\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & -2 & -6 & 4 &\bigm| & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

(this is equivalent to solving $Ax = 0$).

The remainining linearly independed row vectors generate the kernel.

*Relative to the standard basis* means that your matrix has been evaluated on the standard basis $e_1,e_2,...,e_5$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$. In other words: the columns of your matrix are the images of each standard basis vector

$$T(e_1) = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, T(e_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix},... $$

and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 row is a multiple of the second row. We have 2 independent row vectors.  The dimension of the kernel will be 3.

$\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is in the kernel.

We need two more.

Consider,
$\begin{bmatrix} -5\\u\\v\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -9\\w\\x\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

We know that whatever the values of $u,v,w,x$ are, they will first row will multiply to $0.$  Find values that make $0$ when multiplied by the other rows.

Clearly these 3 vectors are independent.